# Plotting with years in python

Tags: python

I have data in my excel file as shown below which I have imported into python and trying to plot the same,

```
Year    Andhra Pradesh
1973-74 50.67
1977-78 69.66
1983    115.4
1993-94 288.7
1999-00 453.61
2004-05 603.82
2009-10 1233.76
2011-12 1753.96
```

However, I am getting a blank plot whenever I run the command.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data1= pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\3004\\Desktop\\Variables.xlsx',2)
plt.plot(data1)
```

I want the years on x axis and the values shown on a histogram or any other plot. However, I receive a blank plot.

Comment: what are your data types for data1? `data1.dtypes`?

Comment: Try `plt.plot(data1['Year'], data1['Andhra Pradesh'])`

Comment: `read_excel` returns a DataFrame, while `plot` expects `(x , y)` separately as an array-like type.

Comment: It’s showing “list”

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.plot(data1)
```

returns

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

You need to pass `x` and `y` separatly in `plt.plot(x,y)`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['1973-74', 50.67],
    ['1977-78', 69.66],
    ['1983   ',115.4],
    ['1993-94',288.7],
    ['1999-00',453.61],
    ['2004-05',603.82],
    ['2009-10',1233.76],
    ['2011-12',1753.96]], 
    columns=['Year','Andhra Pradesh'])

#data1= pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\3004\\Desktop\\Variables.xlsx',2)

plt.plot(data1['Year'], data1['Andhra Pradesh'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataFrame's own [plotting methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html): `data1.plot()`